# angular bind scope data to templateCache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, angular-templatecache

I have this function in my controller, which loads in a template

```
$http.get('scripts/routes/template.html', { cache : $templateCache})
    .then(function(val){
        var returnedTemplate = val.data; // returns string
        $scope.name = 'blah blah';
        $scope.message = 'Good day';
    });
```

The template that that it loaded in by `val.data`, is a string

```
<h3 class="md-title">{{name}}</h3>
<p class="md-title">{{message}}</p>
```

How do I get the string that is returned from the loaded template and bind the scope vars to the string?

The result I need is

```
<h3 class="md-title">blah blah</h3>
<p class="md-title">Good day</p>
```

I have tried to use the $compile functions to bind the data to the string but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to manually compile the html after the binding. create a directive like this.

```
.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

then call this in the html and bind the html string to directive

```
<div dynamic="returnedTemplate"></div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.name = 'blah blah';
 $scope.message = 'Good day';
 $scope.returnedTemplate = '<h3 class="md-title">{{name}}</h3><p class="md-title">{{message}}</p>'
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

        $scope.name = 'blah blah';
        $scope.message = 'Good day';
 $scope.returnedTemplate = '<h3 class="md-title">{{name}}</h3><p class="md-title">{{message}}</p>'
}).directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div dynamic="returnedTemplate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, you definitely pointed me in the write direction. After much playing around I came up to this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction, this is the solution that works best for my set up.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope, $compile, $timeout){
        $scope.name = 'blah blah';
        $scope.message = 'Good day';
        var returnedTemplate = '<div><h3 class="md-title">{{name}}</h3><p class="md-title">{{message}}</p></div>';
        var element = $compile(returnedTemplate)($scope);

        $timeout(function() {
            var confirmDialogMessage = element.html(); // needed time
            console.log(confirmDialogMessage); // here I got the html with values in, but still in a string

       }, 300);
        
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl"></div>
```